# Problem to enconde table to json (string index expected, got number)

Tags: json, lua, lua-table

I have the following table:

`local my_table = {data = {{value1 = "test1", value2 = "test2"}, {value3 = "test3", value4 = "test4"}}}`

I want to convert this table to json format and save to a file. But, when I tried

```
json.encode(my_table)
```

I got an error: *bad argument #1 to 'encode' (["data"] => string index expected, got number)*

I expect the json:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "value1":"test1",
         "value2":"test2"
      },
      {
         "value3":"test3",
         "value4":"test4"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Which library do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!

```
local json = require'json'
local my_table = {data = {{value1 = "test1", value2 = "test2"}, {value3 = "test3", value4 = "test4"}}}
print(json.encode(my_table))  -- {"data":[{"value1":"test1","value2":"test2"},{"value4":"test4","value3":"test3"}]}
```

I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua)

Probably, the implementation you are using requires special syntax to treat Lua table as JSON array instead of JSON dictionary.
The implementation I'm using makes this decision (is it an array or a dictionary) automatically.

Comment: You are right! I was using the lua-json that have this problem! Thank you Eskri.